# Using Vuejs & Axios leads to DOM render delay in style binding, and non-responsiveness

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, axios

I've checked other posts and can't find anything wrong with my code yet.

So I am using async await to make an Axios request and set relevant variables (this code executes when the user clicks a button to show a listing of businesses):

```
try {
    var res = await axios.get(`/businesses`)
    this.WalkOutBusinesses = res.data.businesses
    this.businessNotActivated = false
    this.showBusinesses = true
    this.topGeoIconClass = 'defaultSVGBox_one'
    this.bottomGeoIconClass = 'defaultVGBox_two'
    this.pathSVGClassForChangingColor = ''
    this.nearbyWalkOutsFound = true
    this.findMe()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    alert('Having technical issues! Cannot connect to WalkOut businesses.')
    this.topGeoIconClass = 'defaultSVGBox_one'
    this.bottomGeoIconClass = 'defaultVGBox_two'
    this.pathSVGClassForChangingColor = ''
  }
```

And then setting directives:

```
<div
      @click="business.activated = !business.activated"
      :style="{height: (business.activated ? '420px' : '240px')}"
      style="border: 1px solid black"
      :key="index"
      v-if="showBusinesses"
      class="nearbyBusiness"
      v-for="(business, index) in WalkOutBusinesses"
          >
          {{ index }}
      <img :src="getPic(business.profileImage)">

      {{ business.label }}
      <span class="description">
      {{ business.description }}
    </span>

</div>
```

I would like for the div to change its height when the user clicks it. If I use a regular object I set in my client-side javascript code to test it, it works fine. (I.e., the div gets taller when I click, then shrinks back down when I click again.) But when I call the object from my API with Axios, it delays after clicking before it expands by a few seconds, and then doesn't go back to its original size when I click it again. Strange behavior. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I wouldn't use `v-if` on an element with `v-for` if the `v-if` condition is meant to show / hide the entire list. Move the `v-if="showBusinesses"` to a wrapping element. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if

Comment: Wrapping that stuff in a div with v-if exhibits the same behavior. But I hadn't tried that so thanks for the thought!

Comment: This is was solved. It was a common beginner "gotcha." V-if is not sensitive to changes when those changes involve adding properties to objects. So I made sure each business object had an activated property before it reached the vue.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html